Is mocking Christianity kufr
As-salamu alaykum, I have a question, Is mocking the trinity considered kufr or is it not because you don’t believe in it but you are mocking it? Thank you


108 And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah , lest they insult Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus We have made pleasing to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return, and He will inform them about what they used to do.
— Al-'An`am 108

I wouldn't go so far as to say that mocking Christianity — even the Trinity in particular — counts as kufr (for a more detailed explanation what does and does not constitute kufr, please see "Is "X" kufr"), but doing so is directly opposed to Allah's command as quoted above.
It is important to remember that mocking the disbelievers and their beliefs carries with it the risk that they will respond in kind, mocking Allah and Islam. And while that is a grevious sin on their part, the fact that they committed this grevious sin is explicitly your fault and you will bear upon yourself some of the burden of that blasphemy.

No, mocking Christianity/the trinity is absolutely not kufr. Muslims are allowed to mock Christianity, the trinity, and other kuffar beliefs among themselves but not in front of Christians, as Allah said
"And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah, lest they insult Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus, We have made pleasing to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return, and He will inform them about what they used to do."
